# TeXStudio not recognizing installed packages

Tags: packages, texlive, texstudio

When I install a new package to the TeX system using tlmgr, Texstudio is never able to find the package. The package is missing despite me being able to see the package on my system. Even weirder, sometimes the document compiles, even with the error, sometimes not.

If it makes a difference, I installed TexStudio first (not knowing what it was) and then installed TeXlive afterwards.

Comment: Show a small but complete example of your code and tell the  exact error your get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, may I suggest that you use MiKTeX and TeXStudio, that come with automatic installation of packages and an useful administration tool?

If not, can you specify the system that you are using and how did you install your TeX environment to allow for others to answer?

Probably this should be a comment, but I can´t comment!

Comment: I solved the issue by re-installing TexLive and TeXStudio after purging them from my system. Turns out the tlmgr was pointing to the wrong install directory because I didn't give it write access when I installed. (I'm on Ubuntu and I didn't use sudo)

Comment: The TeX editor (TeXstudio in this example) must be installed *after* the package manager (MikTeX, TeXlive).